# ... syntax in the styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the `...` syntax in the styles for? For example `...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject`:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: (height - 20 - 20) / rows - 10,
    width: (width - 10) / cols - 10,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,                          // take up all available space
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: 10,                 // rounded corners
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, // fill up all space in a container
  },
  title: {
    ...defaultStyles.text,
    fontSize: 14,
    marginTop: 4,
  },
  genre: {
    ...defaultStyles.text,
    color: '#BBBBBB',
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 14,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

(This answer is based on assuming that you are asking about the spread(...) syntax in JavaScript)

> The **spread syntax** allows an expression to be expanded in places
>   where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements
>   (for array literals) or multiple variables (for destructuring
>   assignment) are expected.

Syntax

For function calls:

`myFunction(...iterableObj);`

For array literals:

`[...iterableObj, 4, 5, 6];`

For object literals (new in ECMAScript; stage 3 draft):
`let objClone = { ...obj };`

**Spread in object literals**

The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 3) adds spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than Object.assign().

Eg:-

```
var obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };

 var obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };

 var clonedObj = { ...obj1 };

 // Object { foo: "bar", x: 42 }

var mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };

 // Object { foo: "baz", x: 42, y: 13 }
```

Comment: i understand the principle for an object or an array, for the style however, i don' t see the logic to use it for example:    ...defaultStyles.text
  },